# How to SUM the number of duplicates in a range by given value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, worksheet-function, countif

A simple example as below:

```
Column A is the list containing all data
Column B is the list of all unique data in Column A without duplicates
Column C will be the number of duplicates for each item in Column B from Column A
```

How to write a easy formula for cells in Column C to sum each item in Column B from Column A?

I used `=sum(lookup($a$1:$a$10=$B$1))` for C1 but received: *too few arguments for this function*.

[image]

Comment: so column B is already derived? we don't need to build it ?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this, COUNTIF function, https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-4764f197-0127-49fa-9f5a-b188177b6db4

Comment: I manually made Column B :(.......if there is a better way too make columnB, it will be better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple countif() should suffice unless I'm misunderstanding..

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$10,B1)
```

Count if returns the number of times the second argument is found in the first argument (which is a range.)

[image: Example]

Comment: I was just typing that answer in  :P

Comment: The more time I'm on SO the more and more it feels like a typing race. =)

Comment: Well, it helps with typing speed ... I think I'm back up to 90 WPM .. ;)

Comment: @zzevannn When I copy the fomular down to c 5 , all the count range changed from a1 -- a10 to a5 --a15, how can i keep the count range unchanged from a1 --a10 for all cells in column c?

Comment: Use the $ in the ranges. This tells excel it is a fixed reference and it will nto change based on the relative location of the cell its in.This is actually a requirement to not get the rolling range and I've udpated my answer appropriately

Comment: You might consider: `=COUNTIF(A:A,B1)`   as well .. ;)

Answer (score 2):

With a PivotTable may be even simpler:

[image: SO29375269 example]

The unique list is created as part of constructing the PivotTable, and is sorted alphabetically. A Total may also be automatic, for control purposes.

Comment: Considering it was said that the deduped list was being manually made, this is a one-shot answer that avoids that step.