# Sum and count values by group where group name shows once per group

Tags: excel, formatting, sum, pivot-table, excel-2013

Just had a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29375269/how-to-sum-the-number-of-duplicates-in-a-range-by-given-value/29375349#29375349), solved a simple question. Here is one more question.

How can I SUM all values for each `Item` if they are not on the same rows as their item's description? See `Total Value`:

[image]

Comment: Can I do this by formula or vba?

Comment: @pnuts can you give me a bit more detailed steps to do to `total value` if you dont mind, I followed your comment but couldn't get there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in several elements:

1 Convert your strings in ColumnB into values (select all green triangles, click on exclamation mark and on Convert to Number).
2 Fill down (as in comment above)
3 Pivot Table:

[image: SO29376013 example]

Comment: oh, I see, I need to fill in all item names . Thanks , this will work.

Comment: Thanks , it works now with all my data. :) great help.